# How to make an byte by byte drive-image of a hard-drive without / unrecognized filesystem?

Tags: hard-drive, hard-drive-image

After a windows crash a friends hard-drive starts saying "no operating system found", he had hard-drive issues for a while now, and I instructed him to buy a new one. 
Now I want to recover his data.

But before using my usual recovery tools I would like to make a byte by byte image of that hard-drive, so I could restore it if something goes wrong.

Some hdd imaging tools I've tried can only do this if the hdd shows up with a letter aka gets mounted.

P.S. I'm running Windows 7 x64 ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would be quite easy to do in Linux (you could grab a "live CD" of Ubuntu or something if you don't want to actually set up a linux installation). However it requires a little knowledge of your way around Linux/UNIX (its not as difficult as you may think though).

To make the image, you'd run

```
# dd if=/dev/sda of=/mnt/old-drive-backup
```

assuming the drive you want to back up is the device `/dev/sda` and you have a larger drive mounted on `/mnt` (which is empty or has enough space for the image on it).

`dd` is short for `disk dump` and simply copies one disk/file/block device to another. The `if` key stands for the 'input file' and the `of` key stands for the output file.

To restore, if you screw things up, it would be the reverse:

```
# dd if=/mnt/old-drive-backup of=/dev/sda
```

You'll want to be very careful about checking which drive is which in the device list of course, to make sure you don't overwrite the wrong drive.